# Расширение VSCode для написания документации на c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, extension

Подскажите расширение VSCode для работы с комментариями, оформленные специальным образом (xml комментарии), которые необходимы чтобы создавать xml файл, которые можно потом использовать для создания документации.

Вот с такими вещами, для примера

```cs
/// <summary>
/// что-то здесь
/// </summary>
```

Comment: `для работы с комментариями` какой именно? [Оно?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65716253/12888024)

Comment: @aepot не хочется писать теги ручками. Может сниппеты какие есть, чтобы предлагались теги и закрывались сами. Слэши тройные может сами вставали при переводе строки и проч

Comment: @aepot это стоит расширение, но вот эти xml теги не поддтягиваются

Comment: В Visual Studio это делает макрос "///", быть может в VS Code можно подобные макросы писать.

Comment: так в VS Code же вроде можно писать свои сниппеты/макросы, разве нет?

Comment: @Pekor Абсолютно можно, но я думал, может кто то уже написал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел то, что искал [C# XML Documentation Comments](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=k--kato.docomment).

После активации расширения тройной слэш сразу добавляет строки документации в зависимости от сущности перед, которой это используется.

Здесь приведу настройку `settings.json`, которая наглядно показывает какие теги автоматически используются при той или иной конструкции

```json
"docomment.advanced": {
    "cs": {
        "namespace" : {
            "attributes" : ["summary"]
        },
        "class" : {
            "attributes" : ["summary", "typeparam"]
        },
        "interface" : {
            "attributes" : ["summary", "typeparam"]
        },
        "struct" : {
            "attributes" : ["summary"]
        },
        "enum" : {
            "attributes" : ["summary"]
        },
        "delegate" : {
            "attributes" : ["summary", "param", "typeparam", "returns"]
        },
        "field" : {
            "attributes" : ["summary"]
        },
        "property" : {
            "attributes" : ["summary", "value"]
        },
        "method" : {
            "attributes" : ["summary", "param", "typeparam", "returns"]
        },
        "event" : {
            "attributes" : ["summary"]
        }
    }
```